# Found a bug, fixed it , I dont understand why it was bugging?

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, binary-tree, tree-traversal, postfix-notation

I've come across a bug that has now been fixed but I still dont understand the underlying cause for it.

What I would like to do:

Use post-order tree traversal to get postfix expression from a binary tree. This expression will be returned as a list object for example : 
given the expression tree of

```
"((a+1)+1)"
```

I would like my function to return the following list:

```
 ["a","1","+","1","+"]
```

The problem I'm encountering :

Using my function (called postfix) several times in a row just "adds" the newest list to the previous ones. Here's what I mean given the expression tree of

```
"((a+1)+1)"
```

writing

```
 postfix( BinaryTree of "((a+1)+1)")
```

will return

```
 ["a","1","+","1","+"]
```

and calling the function on the same tree again will return

```
["a","1","+","1","+","a","1","+","1","+"]
```

Can someone explain to me why this is happening ? Here is the rest of my code

```
class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self,rootVal,leftBinaryTree=None,rightBinaryTree=None):
        self.key = rootVal
        self.left = leftBinaryTree
        self.right = rightBinaryTree
    def getRootVal(self):
        return self.key
    def getLeftChild(self):
        return self.left
    def getRightChild(self):
        return self.right

""" Tree Traversal """


def postorder(tree):
    if tree != None:
        postorder(tree.getLeftChild())
        postorder(tree.getRightChild())
        print(tree.getRootVal())

""" posfix from tree """                         


def postfix(tree,stack = []):
    if tree!=None:
        postfix(tree.getLeftChild(),stack)
        postfix(tree.getRightChild(),stack)
        stack.append(tree.getRootVal())
    return stack

expression = "((a+1)+1)"
tree = BinaryTree("+",BinaryTree("+",BinaryTree("a"),BinaryTree("1")),BinaryTree("1"))

print(postfix(tree))
print(postfix(tree))
print(postfix(tree))
```

With the following output

```
['a', '1', '+', '1', '+']
['a', '1', '+', '1', '+', 'a', '1', '+', '1', '+']
['a', '1', '+', '1', '+', 'a', '1', '+', '1', '+', 'a', '1', '+', '1', '+'
```

I've found out while writing this out that explicitly using

```
postfix(tree,[])
```

seems to solve the issue. Could someone tell me what the problem was so I can avoid it in the future ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stack[] is present in memory throughout all of the 3 calls to postfix().
So, every time you use the append() it just add the root to the stack list.

This is evident if you observe the 2nd and 3rd lines of your output.'a', '1', '+', '1', '+' occurs once in the first line, twice in the second and thrice in the third.
If you were to call the method again the fourth time 'a', '1', '+', '1', '+' would repeat 4 times in stack[].